# QQuickPaintedItem in a Flickable becomes blurry when the contentwidth is large

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qpainter, qquickitem

I have a class that inherits `QQuickPaintedItem` with which I override `paint()` to draw an audio waveform.

Once the drawing is done I resize `contentWidth` of `Flickable` containing the qml element I create with `qmlRegisterType`.

The larger `contentWidth` the blurrier the content gets. I never draw depending on contentWidth either and paint() isn't called when changing `contentWidth` and the effect is the same when `contentWidth` is hardcodded in the qml file.

I'm not very experienced with Qt and I was wondering if it's the best approach to begin with for drawing a *big* waveform that I can scroll through, zoom in on and interact with and why the content of `Flickable` get blurrier when increasing `contentWidth`.

I tried all the obvious stuff such as setting the render hint to Antialiasing, etc.

Comment: It's possible that this is a redrawing problem. I would recommend you use `QQuickItem` instead of `QQuickPaintedItem` since it's definitely faster.

Comment: I'm logging whenever update() is called or paint() for that matter. It's not redrawing as far as I can tell and the problem appears on the first paint(). I'll try using QQuickItem, thanks.